# R plot : colors not corresponding and legend not what expected

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have simplified my original code to explain my problem.
My goal is to plot  the values from the column "Value" of my data frame[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYL2a.png). Each dot value would have the color mentionned in column "Color". The plot result is not what I want because :

- the colors don't correspond (is that a problem of "factor"?)
- I would like to have only one legend that displays :
  Blue color dot T1, Red color dot T2, green color dot T3

Would anyone know how to get that result?
Thank you for your help !

```
DF <- DF_Total_Tidy[1:9,1:4]
colnames(DF)<-c("Time","Name","Value","Color")
DF[1:9,4]                                                                                  
<-c("blue","blue","blue","red","red","red","green","green","green")
DF$Name<- as.character(DF$Name)
DF[1:9,2]<-c("T1","T1","T1","T2","T2","T2","T3","T3","T3")
DF

Graph<- DF %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=Value,fill=Name,color=Color)) +
  geom_point( size=4)
plot(Graph)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYL2a.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYL2a.png)

Comment: First problem is likely the factor levels. you can solve this with `scale_color_manual(values = c(...))`. The second problem is that the default shape does not have a fill. you need to have a shape with a fill. Also, if you are already mapping the colors out manually, then I would just make both the fill and the color as "Name"

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I should've mentionned I will need to make different kind of plots, using on sepcific temepratures (my example is simplified version, I have many other temperatures in my data set), and that's why I didn't want to use Scale_color_manual... because I would need to change its content for each plot... so my plan is to use the Color column. As far as I understand, if I both fill and color as Name, I will not be using the color column, so I will use the default colors Red Blue Green (and I ll be using other specific colors)

Comment: I have changed my script to bollow, my first problem is solved. The second one remains : having the legend to display : Purple color dot T1, Brown color dot T2, Orange color dot T3
DF <- DF_Total_Tidy[1:9,1:4]
colnames(DF) <- c("Time","Name","Value","Color")
DF[1:9,4]<-c("purple","purple","purple","brown","brown","brown","orange","orange","orange")
DF$Name<- as.character(DF$Name)
DF[1:9,2]<-c("T1","T1","T1","T2","T2","T2","T3","T3","T3")
DF

Graph<- DF %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=Value,fill= Name)) +
  geom_point(colour=DF$Color,size=4)
plot(Graph)

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to provide the color names via a column of your dataset you could use `scale_color_identity(guide = "legend")` where the `guide` argument is needed to add a legend (As a general rule I would recommend to not use something like `DF$color`.). One drawback of providing the colors is that you end up with the color names in the legend. To fix that you have to provide your desired labels via the `labels` argument, for which I use a named vector in my code below. Additionally your categories are ordered according to the color names. Hence, you probably have to use e.g. the `breaks` argument to set the right order of the categories in the legend.
2. To fix your second issue remove the `fill` aesthetic.

Using a minimal reprex based on `mtcars` I first reproduce your issue:

```r
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$color <- with(mtcars, dplyr::case_when(cyl == 4 ~ "blue", cyl == 6 ~ "red", TRUE ~ "green"))
                     
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = color, fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Now, following the instructions outlined above we get:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = color)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_identity(
    guide = "legend",
    labels = setNames(unique(mtcars$cyl), unique(mtcars$color)),
    breaks = c("blue", "red", "green")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in the response. Thank you very much for your detailed answer, it solved my problem.