# Problem displaying correct data in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

The first script below enables me to associate each unique value of cyl to a dot color in the legend.
I now want to have cyl = 4 and cyl = 6 to have the same color (blue). My second script tries to display in the legend blue dot for 4, blue dot for 6 and green dot for 8. But this doesn't workout correctely. Would any one have an idea what I should modify in my script to achieve this? Many thanks !

```
### This works, I get the 3 colors in the legend : 
mtcars$color <- with(mtcars, dplyr::case_when(cyl == 4 ~ "blue", cyl == 6 ~ "red", cyl == 8 ~ "green"))
mtcars$color <- factor(mtcars$color, levels = c("blue","red","green"))

G_mtcars<-mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=hp, y=mpg,color=color)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_identity(
    guide = "legend",
    labels = setNames(unique(mtcars$cyl), unique(mtcars$color)))
plot(G_mtcars)

### When wanting to get 4 and 6 as blue with blue dots and 8 with green dot I get blue dot with 4
### and green dot with 4. The green dot doesn't match with the correct Cyl (8) and I don't get my
### 3 legend lines : dot blue 4, dot blue 6, dot green 8

mtcars$color <- with(mtcars, dplyr::case_when(cyl == 4 ~ "blue", cyl == 6 ~ "blue", cyl == 8 ~ "green"))
mtcars$color <- factor(mtcars$color, levels = c("blue","green"))
[Th][1]
G_mtcars<-mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=hp, y=mpg,color=color)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_identity(
    guide = "legend",
    labels = setNames(unique(mtcars$cyl), unique(mtcars$color)))
plot(G_mtcars)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below that uses `scale_color_identity()` worked for me.

Note the following:

- **the code is general**, in the sense that if you change the colors, the result will change accordingly (even if you use three different colors as e.g. `c("blue", "red", "green")`
- I use red color instead of blue for values `4` and `6` in order to show that the **color mapping is correctly defined**, even when the color for `4` and `6` (`"red"`) comes after the color for `8` (`"green"`) in alphabetical order.

--

```
#-- Point colors and Legend colors definition
# Define a *named* colors array (where the names are the values of `cyl`)
# so that we can easily define the column `mtcars$color`
# by simply referencing the column `mtcars$cyl`,
# and easily create the legend colors.
colors_cyl = c("4"="red", "6"="red", "8"="green")
# Create the colors to use in the legend by unifying the labels having the same color
# using a hyphen as separator (e.g. "4-6" will be the label for the color assigned to "4" and "6")
colors_legend = setNames(unique(colors_cyl),
                         unique(sapply( colors_cyl,
                                        function(col) paste( names(colors_cyl)[colors_cyl==col],
                                                             collapse="-" ) )) )

#-- Create column in the data frame to plot defining the color mapping
# Create the `color` column in the dataset to plot based on the mapping given in `colors_cyl`
mtcars$color = colors_cyl[ as.character(mtcars$cyl) ]
# Set the order of the colors to the same order as the values of the variable (`cyl`)
# defining the colors, so that the colors are correctly mapped to values.
mtcars$color <- factor(mtcars$color, levels=colors_legend)

# Plot
G_mtcars<-mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=hp, y=mpg, color=color)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_identity(
    guide = "legend",
    name = "cyl",
    labels = names(colors_legend))
plot(G_mtcars)
```

This is the generated plot:
[image]

Comment: Hi Mastropi, sorry for the delay and many thanks for your answer that did the job !

Comment: You are welcome! (glad to know you saw the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `scale_color_manuel` with `values` and `labels` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
mtcars$color <- with(mtcars, dplyr::case_when(cyl == 4 ~ "blue", cyl == 6 ~ "blue2", cyl == 8 ~ "green"))
G_mtcars<-mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=hp, y=mpg,color=color)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('blue' = 'blue', 'blue2' = 'blue', 'green' = 'green'),
                     labels = c('4', '6', '8'))
plot(G_mtcars)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I want to stick to the scale color identity path I have chosen for the reasons I have mentionned on my last post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73854962/r-plot-colors-not-corresponding-and-legend-not-what-expected/73856510#73856510). So I would like to avoid the scale color manual function. And use a column with the colors.

Comment: By the way I have succeeded in doing what I wanted with scale color identity function by setting two blue colors very close to each other, but this is not very elegant and makes me look for close colors for each couple of data ...each time (time consuming)

Comment: @User Why don't you simply define the same color name for the two groups? Referring to your previous post with code `73854962` you would use the `dplyr::case_when()` function as follows: `dplyr::case_when(cyl == 4 ~ "blue", cyl == 6 ~ "blue", TRUE ~ "green"))` , i.e. you would set to `"blue"` the colors of both groups `cyl == 4`  and `cyl == 6`. I think this would work unless color names are required to be all different by `scale_color_identity()`... which I didn't see mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @mastropi, thank you for your help. If my understanding is correct of what you propose, that's exactely the code I displayed in the question of this current post? (using scale_color_identity and  dplyr::case_when(cyl == 4 ~ "blue", cyl == blue ~ "blue", cyl == 8 ~ "green"). As I said in the post, the colors of the dots on the graph are correct. But the legend only displays one the 2 names for the blue color. I need to display both names?

Comment: @User Right... my fault. Please see the answer I just posted.