# How can I display correctely color referencing in legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am reopening the discussion I had here: [Problem displaying correct data in legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73918747/problem-displaying-correct-data-in-legend/73934339#73934339)

I would like to know if there is an easy way to display legend color references when 2 parameters have the same color curves or points. Here is the script showing that the plot's legend displays only one of the 2 parameters in red:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("lubridate")
library("ggplot2")

Time <- c("09-01-2023 12:07:09","09-01-2023 12:17:09","09-01-2023 12:27:09","09-01-2023 12:37:09")
Width <- c(3,4,5,6)
Length <- c(30,40,50,60)
Weight <- c(300,400,500,600)
Angle <- c(3000,4000,5000,6000)

DF <- data.frame(Time,Width,Length,Weight,Angle)
DF<- DF %>% mutate(Time=dmy_hms(Time))
DF_Tidy<-gather(DF,key=Parameters,value=Values,-Time)   
Colors<-c("red","red","red","red","blue","blue","blue","blue",
          "red","red","red","red","green","green","green","green")
Units <-c("mm","mm","mm","mm","mm","mm","mm","mm","kg","kg","kg","kg","Deg","Deg","Deg","Deg")
DF_Tidy<-data.frame(DF_Tidy,Units,Colors)
Graph_DF<-DF_Tidy %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=Values,color=Colors)) +
geom_point() +
scale_color_identity(
guide = "legend",
labels = setNames(DF_Tidy$Parameters, DF_Tidy$Colors))+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10),axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
legend.text=element_text(size=8),legend.key.size = unit(0.5,"line"),legend.position = "bottom")+
facet_wrap(facets = (~ Units),scales="free_y",nrow=4)
plot(Graph_DF)  `
```

I have attached the plot + legend result.
If I replace one the 2 sets of 4 red colors by a set of 4 brown colors, I do get 4 colors (red, blue, brown, green) in my legend (because there are no 2 parameters with the same color (red))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfsKb.png)

In other words, I would like the legend to appear as below:

blue point: Length
red point: Width
red point: Weight
green point: Deg

Is there a way to do this (another way than the one provided in my last post)?
Thank you for your help.
User

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use `interaction` to combine the `color` and `shape` to have 2 labels with red colors like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library("lubridate")
library("ggplot2")

Graph_DF<-DF_Tidy %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=Values,color=interaction(Colors, Parameters), shape = interaction(Colors, Parameters))) +
  geom_point() +
     scale_colour_manual(name = "legend",
                   values = c("blue", "green", "red", "red"),
                   labels = c("Length", "Deg", "Width", "Weight"))+
     scale_shape_manual(name = 'legend',
                   values = c(16, 16, 16, 17),
                   labels = c("Length", "Deg", "Width", "Weight"))+
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10),axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
                       legend.text=element_text(size=8),legend.key.size = unit(0.5,"line"),legend.position = "bottom")+
                 facet_wrap(facets = (~ Units),scales="free_y",nrow=4)
plot(Graph_DF)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi Quinten, thank you for your answer. That could be a way of working around it... but I would like to keep exactely the same representation for the data of the same color (this helps when I need to explain de datas to someone). Added to that my representation could use lines instead of points.

Comment: I have to add that my purpose is to use that color column as the place where I set the colors to each value : in order not to have to deal with any color vectors elsewhere in the script wether it is for the chart it self or the legend. The data frame I have used is a very simplified extract of the orignal one. And having a color column really makes it easier for me. However, I d'ont know if what I am looking is possible in R.